# use the name of a file to assign a permission

Tags: linux, permissions

if i have a file named 500
and i would like to use this name to assign it as permission to the same file with xarg
i need a command to do it for all the directory i have
i used this
command with xargs

- List item

`find -name [0-9]* -print0 |xargs -0 chmod -0`

> **to make the file name 777 for example as permission**

**but it doesn't work**

Is anyone able to help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a loop, for example:

```sh
for file in $(find -name [0-9]* 2>/dev/null); chmod -0 $file
```

Comment: i should definitely use xargs

Comment: `find -name "[0-9]*" -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 chmod -x` this worked for me
What's th output of your command ?

Comment: in your command you removed -x but what i actualy want is if there is a file named 777 i have to put 777 as permission , and if there is 500 i have to put the same permission which is 500

Comment: Try this, but it won't work recursively :/
`find -name "[0-9]*" 2>/dev/null | xargs -i basename {} | xargs -i chmod {} {}`

Comment: @samirabel any updates ?